# The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported.Why this error occur

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions

How to fix it When I try to add this extension id("kotlin-android-extensions") and execute the program the error occured this is the error ->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2YI.png) The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is no longer supported. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

I want to add this extensions id("kotlin-android-extensions") to avoid the findViewById() write everytime. Kindly give me solution for this

Comment: This plugin has been deprecated for a long time and it already reached the point where it is not supported and using it is considered an error. Replacements have been linked in the message you've received.